# Razor view engine, parse directly to file

Tags: .net, razor, spark-view-engine

Bit of stab in the dark here.

We currently use the Spark view engine to help render an xml template that is used within our application for reporting purposes. It works nicely however we have hit a hurdle in that some of our xml templates, once processed, are very large. So large in fact they are causing a problem to run directly in memory. Because of this we are exploring the possibility of writing them straight to disk.

Now, it looks like this may be possible with Spark as you can pass a `TextWriter` in to the render method. But I'm unsure as to whether this is possible with the Razor view engine. Possibly using a technique similar to that described in this post.

http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/29/razor-view-engine-without-mvc-at-all/

Like I say, bit of a stab in the dark but any help appreciated.

Comment: As you've alluded to, this is definitely possible with Spark. I'm not sure you can decouple razor entirely from System.Web or System.WebPages and still retain all rendering functionality, but you might not need all that if you're just outputting XML.

Comment: I've done plenty of hunting on this now and still no luck. We may have to stay with spark